# Useless use of numeric lt (<) in void context

Tags: perl

I am sorry for the probably stupid question, but I get the following warning:

```
"Useless use of numeric lt (<) in void context"
```

when running this code:

```
   for (my $j=0, my $k = 0; $j < @name,$k < @name_mod;) {               
        #doing something   
   }
```

Anyone know how to fix it?,
 Any suggestion greatly appreciated

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? It looks like you're trying to run double loop iterators, but a good answer would depend on _why_ you're trying to do that.

Comment: Because of i need to compare the two arrays at a time.

Comment: Why can you not simply use the same iterator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so - from the comments - you're comparing two arrays.

Presumably inside your loop you're doing something like:

```
 if ( $name[$j] == $name_mod[$k] ) {
```

So my suggestion would be - don't do it like that:

```
for ( my $index = 0; $index < @name and $index < @name_mod; $index++ ) { 
    if ( $name[$index] == $name_mod[$index] ) { 
         #do something
     }
}
```

Or perhaps: [`each_array`](http://search.cpan.org/~rehsack/List-MoreUtils-0.413/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm#each_array_ARRAY1_ARRAY2_...)

```
my $ea = each_array(@name, @name_mod);
while ( my ($cur_name, $cur_name_mod ) = $ea->() )   { .... }
```

Answer (score 6):

A for loop in perl should look like this:

```
for (INITIALIZE; TEST; STEP) {
  BODY;
}
```

In this case: `my $j=0, my $k =0` is your INITIALIZE part. Your TEST (condition) consists of `$j < @name,$k < @name_mod`. This should evaluate to a boolean (`true` or `false`). The error is because there is a `,` between your two tests. You probably want to replace that `,` with either `&&`, the AND operator, or with `||`, the OR operator.

Making your code look like this:

```
for (my $j=0, my $k = 0; $j < @name && $k < @name_mod; ) {               
    #doing something   
}
```

My experience with perl is limited but I think if you have an expression such as `output = TEST1,TEST2` it will probably result in `output == TEST2` leaving `TEST1` to be ignored. Thus resulting in an error of a useless comparison.

Comment: I would also suggest that this sort of operation is a bad choice for a `for` loop anyway, since it has no iterator increment.

Comment: The result of `output = TEST1, TEST2` depends on context, i.e. the type of output. For scalar `$output`, you get TEST1 (because of precedence, you can get TEST2 from `$output = ( TEST1, TEST2 );`). For `@output`, an array, you get TEST1 without parentheses and both TESTs with them.

Answer (score 5):

The question has already been answered, but I'll explain why you're seeing that particular warning. It has to do with the incorrect use of the [comma operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator). The comma operator discards the results of all arguments except for the last. Since it doesn't need the results all but the last argument, it provides a `void` context for them. Here's a way to find out:

```
use v5.10;

sub print_context {
    my $name = shift;

    print "$name ";

    if (wantarray) {
        say "list"
    } elsif (defined wantarray) {
        say "scalar"
    } else {
        say "void";
    }
}

for (; print_context(1), print_context(2), print_context(3); ) {
    last
}
```

The output is:

```
1 void
2 void
3 scalar
```

Thus, it can be seen that the first 2 arguments get a  void context and the last one gets a scalar context (since the `for` loop expects a scalar in the condition part). Since the `<` operator expects you to use the result of the comparison, it shows a warning if used in a void context where the result would be lef unused.

Comment: Yours best answers the question: "Why is he getting this error?", so it's worth my +1. Fixing issues is important, but knowing what a compiler is complaining about is also important (which is why you are fixing it).

Comment: Good explanation from an interpreter's perspective.